# How can I determine if Grails application under testing?

Tags: testing, grails, spock

I need to determine if my Grails application is currently under testing. I cannot use `if (Environment.getCurrent() == Environment.TEST)`, because my current environment is `Environment.CUSTOM` with name jenkins. Is there an other way to find out if it's currently under testing?

Answer (score 2):

One approach I've used is to set an environment variable by hooking into the `eventTestPhaseStart` GANT event. You can do this by creating a script named `Events.groovy` in `/scripts`.

`<project dir>/scripts/Events.groovy`:

```
eventTestPhaseStart = { args ->
    System.properties['grails.testPhase'] = args
}
```

You can use it like so to determine if the app is under testing:

```
if (System.properties['grails.testPhase'] != null)
    println "I'm testing!"
```

You can also use it to have specific behavior for a particular test phase:

```
if (System.properties['grails.testPhase'] == 'integration')
    println "Do something only when running integration tests."
```

Comment: Thank you, that's an approach I've been looking for. I hoped that there was something already built-in.