# Grails - How to make a piece of code run only during functional test

Tags: grails

I have a piece of code in my application, that should run only during functional testing. It should not be execute while unit-testing or integration-testing or during "run-app".

```
if( Environment.current == Environment.TEST )
```

Is there anything similar to the above check, that would check for functional-testing?

Comment: Changing your implementation for the purpose of making a test run is generally not a good idea. Can give a bit more background? What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there's another approach...

Comment: I know its not a good idea. But for many reasons this must be done. Lets say, this would save a lot of system resources and execution time and testing these lines of code isn't important.

Comment: Maybe you could refactor the code that should only run during functional tests into a separate component. You could then use an 'environments' block in Config.groovy to inject your functional test-only component when running in functional test mode

Comment: Actually, I think the block needs to be in resources.groovy. I do something similar in one of my apps where I need to stub a service for non-production environments. Something like this: switch (Environment.current) { case Environment.DEVELOPMENT: ... }

Comment: I need to differentiate between a unit-test and a functional-test. The "Environment.current" would just say its a TEST environment. It wont mention the whether its unit-test or functional test. My code should run for unit test, but not for functional-test.

Comment: If it needs to run for unit tests, then just write unit tests that test the method / class etc. If it needs to not run for functional or integration tests then I think it should be fine to use dependency injection to inject a no-op implementation of your service using an Environment.current switch block in resources.groovy.

Comment: Environment.current is the same for both cases(unit and functional). How can i differentiate between them(unit and functional)? That's the question.

Comment: That's true, but for unit testing you'll be mocking your class's dependencies. Dependencies that you specify in resources.groovy won't be injected for unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar requirement in one of our projects.

The approach was to set a system property with the current test phase. To do so create a file `scripts/Events.groovy` with the following content:

```
eventTestPhaseStart = { args ->
    System.properties["grails.test.phase"] = args
}
```

Now you can perform logic depending on the content of this property:

```
if (System.properties["grails.test.phase"] == "functional") {
    // do something
}
```

This is very similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480975/how-can-i-determine-if-grails-application-under-testing/16484527#16484527) or this [blog entry](http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/02/setting-grails-functional-test-database/).

Comment: Thanks.. this does work. +1 Vote up. But let me wait for a better solution. One that doesn't involve Events. If there is no better solutions. I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice if there would be some built-in way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

`GrailsUtil.environment == 'test'`

Comment: Am sorry, but how does that differentiate between 'functional test' and 'unit test'?